# Which is the preferred method for writing "guards"?

Tags: haskell

I’ve created a function in which I can use (as far as I know) case expressions or guards.

```
foo a b c = case a of 1 -> [...]
                      2 -> [...]
                      3 -> [...] 
                      [...]
                      otherwise -> error "..."
```

or

```
foo a b c | a == 1 = [...]
          | a == 2 = [...]
          | a == 3 = [...] 
          | [...]
          | otherwise = error "..."
```

So, the question is: which of those 2 (case or guards) are “better” coding? Are both basically the same?

Comment: In your first example, you shouldn't use `otherwise` like that. What it does is that it will introduce a new variable called `otherwise = a`, which can lead to subtle bugs. You should do `_ -> error "..."` instead.

Comment: @dflemstr thanks for the info and explication.

Comment: As a general cross-language tip, I prefer to write subblocks of code on the next line and always with the same indentation level. This protects you from having to reindent the remaining lines if the first one changes in length (perhaps due to foo being renamed or something line that)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first one is considered better style, for 2 reasons.

First of all: Many people would say that it looks better, since you don't have to type out all of the `==`. This is a very subjective reason, of course. Also, you would normally not  even introduce a new case statement, but just match the arguments in the function argument list like so:

```
foo 1 b c = ... -- etc
...
foo _ b c = ... -- for the "otherwise" part
```

This makes the code even more compact and readable, which many people like.

Secondly, there actually is a semantic difference. Imagine that you have a data type like this:

```
data Cake = Apple | Cheese | Cream
```

If you use the first method, you match against the constructors in the `case..of` expression:

```
case a of
  Apple -> "fruit"
  _     -> "not fruit"
```

However, if you try to do a guarded expression of some sort, like this:

```
| a == Apple = "fruit"
| otherwise  = "not fruit"
```

... it won't actually work, because the `Cake` type doesn't have an `Eq` instance, so you can't use `==` to compare two values. Introducing an `Eq` instance (with `deriving (Eq)` after the data definition) is not always wanted, so not having to do it in this case might be significant.

Comment: How you could you say one is better than the other if they are semantically different?

Comment: @AdamWagner because in many situations, you have the option to use either one with exactly the same results (by "comparing the resulting machine code").

Comment: Note that if you use a case statement instead of direct pattern matching in the function definition, the different cases can share the same `where` clause, as can guards.

Answer (score 9):

When a guard can be rewritten as a (guardless) case-statement on one of the parameters, it's not actual necessary. I.e. you can just write it as:

```
foo 1 b c = [...]
foo 2 b c = [...]
foo 3 b c = [...]
[...]
```

Which is the preferred way to write it. You'd use guards when the condition you want can't be expressed as a pattern. And you'd use a case-statement when you need to match on something other than one of the parameters.

Comment: Actually, I have some base cases (I believe I can call them base case – I’m a beginner in codding), like “if a == 1 && b>c then (...)” . So, If a apply your suggestion, it could make my code a little less readable, I guess (?).

Comment: Actually (part 2) ... I gess I can aplly your suggestion... and it looks good! ^^